# Where do I find the the set of protocols available to use for each layer in the unet stack?

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to develop a customised protocol stack for the unet simulator. I want to know the options available to me for each layer.
Also I want to use existing protocols rather develop them from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of agents available in the default UnetStack installation in the `etc/setup.groovy` file in the installation directory. Here's an extract from the current release version:

```java
loadAgentByClass 'arp',          'org.arl.unet.addr.AddressResolution'
loadAgentByClass 'ranging',      'org.arl.unet.localization.Ranging'
loadAgentByClass 'mac',          'org.arl.unet.mac.CSMA'
loadAgentByClass 'uwlink',       'org.arl.unet.link.ECLink', 'org.arl.unet.link.ReliableLink'
loadAgentByClass 'transport',    'org.arl.unet.transport.SWTransport'
loadAgentByClass 'router',       'org.arl.unet.net.Router'
loadAgentByClass 'rdp',          'org.arl.unet.net.RouteDiscoveryProtocol'
loadAgentByClass 'statemanager', 'org.arl.unet.state.StateManager'

container.add 'remote', new org.arl.unet.remote.RemoteControl(cwd: new File(home, 'scripts'), enable: false)
container.add 'bbmon',  new org.arl.unet.bb.BasebandSignalMonitor(new File(home, 'logs/signals-0.txt').path, 64)
```

In most cases, this lists one agent class (e.g. `org.arl.unet.addr.AddressResolution`) per service (e.g. providing `ADDRESS_RESOLUTION` service).

In some cases, multiple agents are listed (e.g. `org.arl.unet.link.ECLink` and `org.arl.unet.link.ReliableLink`) for the same service. In this case, each agent is attempted to be loaded in succession. The `org.arl.unet.link.ECLink` agent is only available in the premium edition (and not in the downloadable community edition). So, in the community edition, this will load `org.arl.unet.link.ReliableLink` to provide the `LINK` service.

While these are the default agents in the UnetStack distribution, you can add/replace any of these with your own, or by agents written by others in the community. You can find some of the community agents in the [unet-contrib](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib) repository, or in other personal Github repositories (e.g. [dtn-unetstack](https://github.com/shortstheory/dtn-unetstack)).